# Is it possible to add Shapes from a Canvas to a 2D array, where the 2D array location is that of a Grid control cell underneath?

Tags: c#, silverlight, canvas, grid, multidimensional-array

I know this seems like a complete mess of a question but here goes:

I'm essentially created a simulation within silverlight as a programming exercise.
I have a semi opaque canvas that lives on top of a grid with 40 rows and 30 columns. I can place canvas object into the grid cells to change the colour to represent water, grass, sand or whatever.
I'm having my AI agents exist on the canvas however so that they can be moved smoothly across the surface and not in a jagged way which the grid would do.

Im just wondering if anyone has had any experience with accessing relative coordinate between canvas's and grids. My grid cells are 5x5 where as the canvas points are obviously single digits between 0 and 400. Im just trying to find a way to collect up all the Shapes on the canvas, relative to their grid position.

Please feel free to ask further questions, I am aware it is not very clear. 
Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: if its simply a smoother animation, have you looked into using storyboards at all? for example you would have a from storyboard that goes from the center to the right, the next storyboard would take it in the next cell from the left to the center? same thing goes for all the other cases?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunataly its not quite as simple as that. The shapes move according to certain AI rules like collision and path finding. I feel I may have to ditch the grid and just work with the canvas, which is a shame considering how easy the grid is to manipulate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could still use the grid if you give your agents a RenderTransform. This way they still be inside your grid and can freely move.

Comment: I'll give this some serious consideration. It may be what I'm looking for. New to silverlight, obviously! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help you, but I recently had a similar (albeit only very vaguely similar,) situation.
 What I ended up doing, was setting the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` to `0`, and the `Grid.RowSpan` and `Grid.ColumnSpan` to the number of Rows/Columns in the Grid.  (Easy to do dynamically by just grabbing the `Grid.ColumnDefinitions/RowDefinitions.Count`.)
Then, if you want to make it mimic a Canvas, set `HorizontalAlignment = Left` and `VeritcalAlignment = Top` and then, instead of changing the `Canvas.Top` or `Canvas.Left` just change the `Margin.Top` and `Margin.Left`.
Worked like a dream for me.  The only thing missing is the `Canvas.ZIndex` property.  Unfortunately that's a little more fiddly to emulate, as it involves changing the order of your agents within the `Grid.Children`. When I have problems like that though, I usually end up just creating a property that handles all the technical stuff so I can se tit like an `int`.
Hope this helps, and let me know if you used it and need a hand writing up the `Canvas.ZIndex` faker!

Comment: ... or you could take the easy option and just do what @NestorArturo recommends... `/facepalm`

Comment: The only *minor* downside to NestorArturo's answer, I can think of, is that it can, briefly, be confusing when applying second and third transformations, such as rotating the agent, and/or making it shake. Like I said, *minor*.

Comment: Yeah im finding it very difficult to do any sort of loop for updating agent positions. The application just seems to hang for some reason.